# Question of proper usage for F Macro

Tags: memory-usage

Here are three use cases. Are all preferred or is the use of the `F()` macro pointless on some?

**1.**

```
Serial.println(F("some string"); // definitely useful here
```

**2.**

```
String str = F("some string");
Serial.println(str);
```

**3.**

```
int num = 5;
String str = F("some string with int ");
str += (String)num;
Serial.println(str);
```

Comment: Note that in case 3. you can just use two Serial.print commands like so: `Serial.print(F("some string with int ")); Serial.println(num);`

Comment: @Gerben are there any performance benefits to doing it this way?

Comment: You don't need to use a String object. And you don't need to have a variable for storing the entire string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time String is involved F() becomes pointless. Avoid String like the plague if you value your memory integrity.

Comment: Does this apply to `c++` in general? I just finished replacing `String` with `char*` through my Arduino program's code.

Comment: No. String is a custom Arduino class that does dynamic allocation. F() is also Arduino-specific. When you assign anything to a String it is copied into RAM (dynamically allocated in the heap), so it wastes RAM when you don't need to.

Comment: I have never used String in a program, and I never will use String in a program. It's all `char *` or `const char *`, the latter with PROGMEM when needed, though I don't often use platforms that need it.

Comment: @Majenko, Should I use F() everywhere or with Serial.print* only?

Comment: Use it whenever you have a string literal and a function that will take a FlashString. Anything that inherits `Print` is a good candidate.